# Defining component scoped variables in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

How may I define a variable in component's "init" function which I am able to access across all the component functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use the variables scope, this is private to the component and available inside any function within the component

```
function init(somevalue) {
  variables.somevalue = arguments.somevalue
}

function getSomeValue() {
  return variables.somevalue;
}
```

Comment: Just to expound on the scoping concept, variables scope within a component is private.  "This" scope within a component is public.  "Local" is for variables private to a single function.